# Creating a 3D Matrix in R based on the presence of some specific values in groups of data in a data set

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation

I am working with a data set in R, suppose `mtcars`:

```
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
```

Now I want to create a matrix for each type of transmission `am: (0 = automatic, 1 = manual)` that shows if any of the levels of variable `carb` is present in any of the levels of variable `cyl`. Put it differently, if `cyl` can have the values of `4 , 6 and 8` and `1, 2, 3, 4, 6 and 8` are the possible values for variable `carb`, I want a `3x6` matrix for each transmission type whose elements are 1 if each combination of `cyl-carb` is present in our data and `0` otherwise. Thus, the resulting matrix should be of dimension `2x3x6`. e.g. :

(These matrices are here only for illustrative purposes and their elements are chosen arbitrarily by myself in order to better explain what kind of output I expect)

```
for am == 0
  1 2 3 4 6 8
4 0 0 1 0 1 0
6 1 0 0 1 1 1
8 0 1 0 0 1 0

for am == 1
  1 2 3 4 6 8
4 1 0 0 0 1 0
6 0 1 0 1 0 0
8 0 1 1 0 1 1
```

I know that `dplyr` is quite handy for such data manipulation, but I do not know how to use it in this case where I want to create a matrix based on the groups of variables in another data frame?!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Please share an expected table output, it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a not-quite-elegant brute force approach:

```
mtcars

res <- with(mtcars, array(
    data = 0L,
    dim = c(
        length(unique(cyl )),
        length(unique(carb)),
        length(unique(am  ))
    ),
    dimnames = list(
        paste("cyl",  sort(unique(cyl )), sep = "_"),
        paste("carb", sort(unique(carb)), sep = "_"),
        paste("am",   sort(unique(am  )), sep = "_")
    )
))

for(x in seq_len(dim(res)[1])) {
    for(y in seq_len(dim(res)[2])) {
        for(z in seq_len(dim(res)[3])) {
            if (any(
                mtcars$cyl  == readr::parse_number(dimnames(res)[[1]][x]) &
                mtcars$carb == readr::parse_number(dimnames(res)[[2]][y]) &
                mtcars$am   == readr::parse_number(dimnames(res)[[3]][z])
            )) {
                res[x, y, z] <- 1L
            }
        }
    }
}

res
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, 
though I disagree with you about the elegance of your solution!
Just one question, what does that any() do in the if statement?

Comment: any() checks if any value of the logical vector it inspects is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

We can `split` the subset of data by the 'am' column and get the `table`

```
# convert the 'carb' column to `factor` with `levels` specified
# inorder to get all the combinations
mtcars$carb <- factor(mtcars$carb, levels = sort(unique(mtcars$carb)))
lapply(split(mtcars[c("cyl", "carb")], mtcars$am), function(x) +(table(x) > 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the your nice solution, I learned a lot from it, specially the trick you used to convert the True/False matrix to a 1/0 one!